# Questão de java (junção de do while e switch)

Tags: java, c, loop, do-while

Segue o enunciado da questão:

> Utilize a instrução switch e o laço/loop do-while para implementar uma
> questão de múltipla escolha referente a alguma das outras disciplinas
> que você está cursando neste semestre. Primeiro deverá ser apresentado
> o enunciado da questão com as 5 opções/alternativas de resposta, que
> são (a), (b), (c), (d) e (e). Depois que o usuário escolher uma opção,
> se for a resposta correta deverá ser impresso “Resposta correta”, caso
> contrário “Resposta incorreta”. No caso de “Resposta incorreta” a
> questão deve ser apresentada novamente para outra tentativa. Deve ser
> permitido no máximo 3 tentativas, quando a resposta correta for
> escolhida deve ser informado em qual tentativa isso ocorreu, caso isso
> não ocorra em nenhuma das 3 tentativas deve ser impresso “Resposta
> incorreta nas 3 tentativas”.

Segue meu codigo:

```
public class ADO_06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String operacaoStr;
        char operacao;
        boolean tacerto = false; 
        
            do {
                
                System.out.println("Em um computador o número 2012, em base decimal, será representado, em base binária, por:");
                
                System.out.println("A) 110111");
                System.out.println("B) 110111");
                System.out.println("C) 110111");
                System.out.println("D) 110111");
                System.out.println("E) 110111");
                
                System.out.println("Informe sua resposta: ");
                
                operacaoStr = entrada.next();
                operacao = operacaoStr .charAt(0);
                
                
                switch(operacao) {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("Resposta errada :( ");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("Respota correta!!! :D");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("Resposta errada :( ");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    System.out.println("Resposta errada :(");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    System.out.println("Resposta errada :(");
                    break;
                }
                
                
                
            }while(!tacerto);
            
        }
    
}
```

Não sei o que fazer para repetir três vezes.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o contador para decidir essas três tenrativaS , assim :

```
package repetir.tres.vezes;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
public class RepetirTresVezes 
{   // cor de findo
public static final String ANSI_RESET             = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_BLACK_BACKGROUND  = "\u001B[40m";
public static final String ANSI_RED_BACKGROUND    = "\u001B[41m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  = "\u001B[42m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[43m";
public static final String ANSI_BLUE_BACKGROUND   = "\u001B[44m";
public static final String ANSI_PURPLE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[45m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN_BACKGROUND   = "\u001B[46m";
public static final String ANSI_WHITE_BACKGROUND  = "\u001B[47m";
// cor das letras
public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
// public class ADO_06 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //System.out.println (CSI + "m");
    
    String operacaoStr;
    char operacao;
    boolean tacerto = false; 
    int TentatiBas = 0; // numero de Tentatibas
    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Em um computador o número 2012, em base decimal, será representado, em base binária, por:");
        String CSI = "\u001B[";
        System.out.print (CSI + "31" + "m");

        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  + "A) 110111");
        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  + "B) 110111");
        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  + "C) 110111");
        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  + "D) 110111");
        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND  + "E) 110111");
        System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW_BACKGROUND + "Informe sua resposta: ");
        TentatiBas++;
        operacaoStr = entrada.next();
        operacaoStr.toUpperCase();
        operacao = operacaoStr .charAt(0);
        switch( operacao ) 
        {
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Resposta errada :( ");
            break;
        case 'B':
            System.out.println("Respota correta!!! :D");
            tacerto = true;
            break;
        case 'C':
            System.out.println("Resposta errada :( ");
            break;
        case 'D':
            System.out.println("Resposta errada :(");
            break;
        case 'E':
            System.out.println("Resposta errada :(");
                break;
        }
    }while( TentatiBas < 3 );
    if( TentatiBas > 2 )
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW_BACKGROUND + "Resposta incorreta nas 3 tentativas . !\n");
    }
}
}
```